# How to optimize the WFS service's CQL and ECQL?

Tags: wfs, ogc, cql-filter

I am using  wfs cql filters to get the attribute data but when the cql filter selects a large dataset say 1000+ point data the response time is large.

How can I optimize cql filter ?

The following are my guess

1)if there is option to skip the loading the geometry column then it might speed up the search process and also the network load will be reduced.

2)Also i don't know which index CQL filter is used ? Can i explicitly  use b-tree to make it faster?

Comment: 1) You can list the attributes with &PROPERTYNAME= like here http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&version=1.0.0&service=wfs&typename=topp:states&propertyname=STATE_NAME,EMPLOYED&SORTBY=EMPLOYED&maxfeatures=1 2) CQL does not know anything about what happens behind the WFS server. Server converts the CQL filter to something that is needed for getting the data from datastore. If it is a database then some SQL is generated and it is up to database admin to consider which are the most common WFS queries and which indexes are needed.

Comment: user30184 thanks for your time. In your example there is still geometry data <gml:coordinates > i was hoping to skip this "<gml:coordinates >" in hope to optimize it.

Comment: That is not really the geometry of the feature but the bounding box <gml:boundedBy>. That seems to come for the whole result set and for the feature.  I am not sure if it is compulsory in WFS or if this server is just configured to send it always. That's still the shortest you can get from that server. Or GeoJSON is a bit shorter http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&version=1.1.0&service=wfs&typename=topp:states&propertyname=STATE_NAME,EMPLOYED&SORTBY=EMPLOYED&maxfeatures=1&outputformat=application/json